# Can't See Timeline View in org-agenda

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I type `M-x org-agenda` in org-mode, the list of commands shows, I press `a`, the agenda buffer opens but only shows the dates, and pressing `L` won't expand:-

```
Week-agenda (W27):
Monday      1 July 2019 W27
Tuesday     2 July 2019
Wednesday   3 July 2019
Thursday    4 July 2019
Friday      5 July 2019
Saturday    6 July 2019
Sunday      7 July 2019

================================================================
Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
```

I am seeing the same problem with emacs 24, 25, 26 on Win 7. The same file shows detailed timelines fine on a debian machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported in a now deleted comment, timeline view is no more (org-mode version 9.1 onwards). See https://www.orgmode.org/Changes_old.html

Comment: I was hoping the commenter would come back to answer :)

Comment: related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/67901/recreating-timeline-view